# Android app crashing on startup. Has this anything to do with NullPointerException error? How do I prevent the app from crashing?

Tags: java, android, debugging, crash, android-music-player

I am writing a music player in Java for Android. So far, the app keeps crashing after startup. I'm using Android Studio. I had a look at the 'Logcat' tab at the bottom of the screen and I found the following error message:

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setLooping(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.musicplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
```

Has this anything to do with the app crashing all the time and what can I do to prevent it from crashing?

I tried to run the app in an emulator and a real phone.

```
//activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.musicplayer.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/positionBar"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/elapsedTimeLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0:11"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/remainingTimeLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-1:49"
            android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playBtn"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/play"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:onClick="playBtnClick"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sound"/>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/volumeBar"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progress="50"
            android:max="100"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="26dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sound2"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

//MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.musicplayer;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCo

mpatActivity;

    //import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.SeekBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button playBtn;
        SeekBar positionBar;
        SeekBar volumeBar;
        TextView elapsedTimeLabel;
        TextView remainingTimeLabel;
        MediaPlayer mp;
        int totalTime;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
            elapsedTimeLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.elapsedTimeLabel);


            //Media Player:
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.seekTo(0);
            mp.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f);
            totalTime = mp.getDuration();

            //Position Bar:
            positionBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.positionBar);
            positionBar.setMax(totalTime);
            positionBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
                    new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                            if(fromUser){
                                mp.seekTo(progress);
                                positionBar.setProgress(progress);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }
                    }
            );

            //Volume Bar:
            volumeBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volumeBar);
            volumeBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
                    new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                            float volumeNum = progress / 100f;
                            mp.setVolume(volumeNum, volumeNum);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }
                    }
            );

            //thread update position bar & time label
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (mp != null){
                        try{
                            Message msg = new Message();
                            msg.what = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                            handler.sendMessage(msg);
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        }catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                    }
                }
            }).start();

        }

        private Handler handler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
                int currentPosition = msg.what;
                //update position bar
                positionBar.setProgress(currentPosition);

                //update labels
                String elapsedTime = createTimeLabel(currentPosition);
                elapsedTimeLabel.setText(elapsedTime);

                String remainingTime = createTimeLabel(totalTime-currentPosition);
                remainingTimeLabel.setText("- " + remainingTime);
            }
        };

        public String createTimeLabel(int time){
            String timeLabel = "";
            int min = time / 1000 / 60;
            int sec = time / 1000 % 60;

            timeLabel = min + ":";
            if(sec < 10) timeLabel += "0";
            timeLabel += sec;

            return timeLabel;
        }



        public void playBtnClick(View view){
            if(!mp.isPlaying()){
                //stopping
                mp.start();
                playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop);
            }else{
                //playing
                mp.pause();
                playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            }

        }

    }




    /*I would like the app to start up and keep running so that I can play some music, but instead it closes immediately after I run it. This is the error message I got from Logcat:

    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setLooping(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.musicplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)*/
```

Comment: Can you put up your MainActiviy.java if possible ?

Comment: Yes, it is related to NPE.

Comment: Update: I tried out commenting the following section of the MainActivity.java file. Now the app only closes, when I tap the play buttun.         //Media Player:
//        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
//        mp.setLooping(true);
//        mp.seekTo(0);
//        mp.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f);
//        totalTime = mp.getDuration();

Comment: @Swayangjit OK. MainActivity.java is there now.

Comment: @dSanders Thank you. Good to know. I tried commenting out the affected section of the code. Now the app is running, but I still can't play music on it, because it crashes again when I tap the play button. I get another NullPointerException in line 137. How can I fix this?